# Как изменить номер зарегистрированного телефона в Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Использую вход по номеру телефона Firebase. Есть зарегистрированный номер и теперь я хочу изменить номер на новый. У `FirebaseUser` есть метод `Task<Void> updatePhoneNumber (PhoneAuthCredential credential)`, каким образом получить `credential`?

Comment: Уточните, что именно?

Comment: Вас ничего не смущает? :) Ладно. Не хочу мусорить в вашем вопросе. Прошу прощения, если что.

Comment: Совпадение в никах, бывает такое)